# Отфильтровать строку и выделить значение (Python)

Tags: python

Есть часть вывода в консоли(Windows). Это результат отработанной утилиты.
Нужно с помощью питона выделить одну строку - "|  |  +- Temperature #1 :       37       37       37 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/0)" И в этой строке взять первое числовой значение в данном случае = 37 и вывести его либо обратно в консоль либо записать в текстовый файлик. Нужно брать именно первое числовое значение.

```
    Open Hardware Monitor Report

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version: 0.9.2.0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Common Language Runtime: 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19044.0
Process Type: 64-Bit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sensors

|
+- Gigabyte B360M DS3H (/mainboard)
|  |
|  +- ITE IT8686E (/lpc/it8686e)
|  |  +- Voltage #1     :    0.708    0.708    1.056 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/0)
|  |  +- Voltage #2     :     2.04    2.028     2.04 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/1)
|  |  +- Voltage #3     :    2.028    2.016    2.028 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/2)
|  |  +- Voltage #4     :    2.004    1.992    2.016 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/3)
|  |  +- Voltage #5     :     0.06     0.06    0.348 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/4)
|  |  +- Voltage #6     :     1.08     1.08     1.08 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/5)
|  |  +- Voltage #7     :    1.224    1.224    1.224 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/6)
|  |  +- Standby +3.3V  :    3.408    3.408    3.408 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/7)
|  |  +- VBat           :    3.168    3.168    3.168 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/8)
|  |  +- Temperature #1 :       37       37       37 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/0)
|  |  +- Temperature #2 :       35       35       35 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/1)
|  |  +- Temperature #3 :       21       19       25 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/2)
|  |  +- Temperature #5 :       28       28       28 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/4)
|  |  +- Temperature #6 :       28       28       29 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/5)
|  |  +- Fan #1         :  1088.71     1080  1088.71 (/lpc/it8686e/fan/0)
```

Comment: Ваш-то код где?

Comment: Так вот нету кода. Мне по сути нужен пример кода на питоне который просто отфильтрует и выведет просто цифру и данной строки.
На данный момент имеется bat файл который это делает, но делает он это циклично и поэтапно, то есть сначала отфильтровывает все и данную строку записывает в файл txt. Потом вторым этапом из полученного файла берет только цифру и перезаписывает в другой файл txt.
С помощью питона хотел более оптимизировать.

Answer (score 0):

Да всё просто же:

- перебираете строки
- ищете вхождение нужной строки
- выделяете нужное место через `split`

```py
text = """
    Open Hardware Monitor Report

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version: 0.9.2.0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Common Language Runtime: 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19044.0
Process Type: 64-Bit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sensors

|
+- Gigabyte B360M DS3H (/mainboard)
|  |
|  +- ITE IT8686E (/lpc/it8686e)
|  |  +- Voltage #1     :    0.708    0.708    1.056 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/0)
|  |  +- Voltage #2     :     2.04    2.028     2.04 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/1)
|  |  +- Voltage #3     :    2.028    2.016    2.028 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/2)
|  |  +- Voltage #4     :    2.004    1.992    2.016 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/3)
|  |  +- Voltage #5     :     0.06     0.06    0.348 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/4)
|  |  +- Voltage #6     :     1.08     1.08     1.08 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/5)
|  |  +- Voltage #7     :    1.224    1.224    1.224 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/6)
|  |  +- Standby +3.3V  :    3.408    3.408    3.408 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/7)
|  |  +- VBat           :    3.168    3.168    3.168 (/lpc/it8686e/voltage/8)
|  |  +- Temperature #1 :       37       37       37 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/0)
|  |  +- Temperature #2 :       35       35       35 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/1)
|  |  +- Temperature #3 :       21       19       25 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/2)
|  |  +- Temperature #5 :       28       28       28 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/4)
|  |  +- Temperature #6 :       28       28       29 (/lpc/it8686e/temperature/5)
|  |  +- Fan #1         :  1088.71     1080  1088.71 (/lpc/it8686e/fan/0)
"""

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if 'Temperature #1' in line:
        print(line.split(':')[1].split()[0])
```

Вывод:

```
37
```

Вариант, если читать из сформированного файла с выводом утилиты:

```py
with open(r'C:\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitorReport.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Temperature #1' in line:
            print(line.split(':')[1].split()[0])
```

Comment: Все отлично, только вот текст, а точнее цифры каждый раз разные...
Программа отработала по расписанию каждые 2 минуты, выдала вот такую портянку каждый раз с разными значениями....

Comment: Я вам просто показал, как из этой портянки питоном что-то доставать. Вы же скриптом в файл вывод программы записываете. Ну читайте питоном из этого файла. Сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: Значение показывает, но выдает еще и сообщение:

`Возникло исключение: IndexError
list index out of range
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Python\Untitled-2.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(line.split(':')[1].split()[0])`

Comment: Если вызывать из cmd то:

`37
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Python\Untitled-2.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(line.split(':')[1].split()[0])
IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так сейчас работает. Обычный бат файл

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:repeat

set sum=1
set div=1

call start /B /wait C:\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitorReport.exe ReportToFile --IgnoreMonitorGPU --IgnoreMonitorFanController --IgnoreMonitorHDD --IgnoreMonitorRAM --file C:\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitorReport.txt
find "Temperature #3" C:\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitorReport.txt | find "   " | find "/lpc/it8688e/temperature/2" >C:\OpenHardwareMonitor\Result.txt
for /f "tokens=7 delims= " %%i in (C:\OpenHardwareMonitor\Result.txt) do (set /a sum=!sum!+%%i
    set /a div=!div!+1
)
echo %sum% >C:\OpenHardwareMonitor\temperature.txt

timeout /t 60

goto repeat
```